# What's a level 12 clan? And what should one do when badly losing a Clan War?

Tags: clash-of-clans

People are fighting in chat about the enemy being a "Level 12 Clan." What does this mean? Is it related to clan perks? We're losing the war badly (i.e. the enemy has average destruction 93% and we have 72%.) Is there a point to making sure that everyone attacks, or should we just let everyone do whatever they want?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, by "Level 12 Clan" It means Clan Perk 12 which isn't the maximum (max level 15). Perks don't give extra powers in battle, they only make stuff like donation and war loot better. When a Clan is Level 12 it means they are worked a lot and they are probably a lot stronger then your clan and you should probably save your troops on the clan war and just have fun.

If you want to learn more about clan perks visit [this page](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Clan_Perks)

Comment: I know how to see the clan perks for MY CLAN but how do you know what the enemy in war has?

Comment: You search for the clan and match the badge and players. The clan perk should be there

Comment: What to do when your ridiculously out matched in war? This clan has average of 97% destruction and has already almost 3 stared all bases.

Comment: Ignore the war because you will lose or you could play for the loot

Answer (score 0):

Your clan might be taking many heigher TH Level members suppose you take 4-3 TH10 members you will be matched according to that. So take care that there are limited high TH in one WAR.

Answer (score 0):

Clan level higher than yours do not mean that your clan is at a disadvantage at war. But it does mean they have had wars far more than yours and might have won many of them.  But if your clan has players who are better at strategizing and attacking and have good war experience , Sure,you can win the war.

The purpose of the clan wars is to show team work and strategies and have fun as a clan.
Happy Clashing